# Why doesn't Rails throw an exception when we access an undefined instance variable in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose we have the following implementation:

app/controllers/cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsControllers < ApplicationController
  def index
    @test = '7'
  end
end
```

app/views/cars/index.html.erb

```
My test variable is <%= @test %>.
Here is an undefined variable <%= @test2 %>.
```

How come accessing @test2 doesn't throw an exception (Given we are trying to access an instance variable)?

Comment: Because this is how Ruby works and it can be easily be confirmed in an IRB console. Therefore your question is unclear to me. Can you please elaborate on why you think it should raise an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't pose a problem in your example because `@test2` simply returns `nil` when undefined.

You can verify this in an irb console session:

```
2.6.2 :001 > @test2
 => nil
```

However ... if you were to call a method assumed to be provided by `@test2` then you'd have a problem:

```
2.6.2 :002 > @test2.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)
```

In that case, you definitely would receive an error when Rails tried to render the view.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined `instance variable` value will always `nil`, If you will access it, it will not throw any exception, while local variable will throw exception if did not defined it, if you want to check instance variable is assigned or not you can use `.present?` method.

Here are simple example of it

`Instance variable`

```
2.5.1 :009 > @undefined
 => nil 
2.5.1 :010 > @undefined.present?
 => false 
2.5.1 :011 > defined? @undefined
 => nil 

2.5.1 :014 > @defined = "test"
 => "test" 
2.5.1 :015 > @defined.present?
 => true 
2.5.1 :016 > defined? @defined
 => "instance-variable"
```

`Local variable`

```
2.5.1 :017 > undefined_local
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):17
NameError (undefined local variable or method `undefined_local' for main:Object)
2.5.1 :018 > undefined_local.present?
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):18
NameError (undefined local variable or method `undefined_local' for main:Object)
2.5.1 :019 > defined? undefined_local
 => nil 
 2.5.1 :020 > defined_local = "test"
 => "test" 
2.5.1 :021 > defined? defined_local
 => "local-variable"
```

Hope this is enough to understand the concept

Answer (score 2):

In most programming languages, instance variables must be declared before they can be assigned. Ruby is the diametric opposite – instance variables cannot be declared at all. Instead, an instance variable in Ruby comes into existence the first time it is assigned.

That's why accessing an instance variable that has not been assigned does not raise an error.

@test2 is nil when it is accessed before assignment.

See docs: https://www.sitepoint.com/common-trip-ups-new-rubyists-part/